# VBA in excel- Start different sub macros at different time intervals

Tags: excel, vba

This is my main macro which repeats every 5 minute and starts other macros, which works very well. My question is how can I add `macro4` at the end only running in an interval for 1 hour/1 day instead of every 5 minute?

I don't want to start another main macro, because at some time these two will run simultaneously and make a mess in my Excel book.

```
Public Sub start()
    macro1
    macro2
    macro3
    alerttime = Now + TimeValue("00:05:00")
    Application.OnTime alerttime, "start"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about potential conflict but to simply change time use `TimeSerial`

```
Now + Timeserial(Hour as Integer,Minute As Integer, Second As Integer)
```

Specify the required times for the appropriate argument e.g. Hour = 1